# Custom Joomla 3.4 Finder Plugin Not Displaying in Results

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, smartsearch

I have created a custom finder plugin to reference my custom component content, however, the content indexes as expected but it doesn't show up in the results on the front end.

Have I missed a step?

```
protected function index(FinderIndexerResult $item, $format = 'html')
{
    // Check if the extension is enabled
    if (JComponentHelper::isEnabled($this->extension) == false)
    {
        return;
    }

    $item->setLanguage();

    // Initialize the item parameters.
    $registry = new Registry;
    $registry->loadString($item->params);
    $item->params = $registry;

    // Initialize the item parameters.
    $registry = new Registry;
    $registry->loadString($item->info);
    $item->info = $registry;

    // Trigger the onContentPrepare event.
    $item->description = FinderIndexerHelper::prepareContent($item->description, $item->params);

    // Build the necessary route and path information.
    $item->url = $this->getUrl($item->id, $this->extension, $this->layout);
    $item->route = AgshowsHelperRoute::getShowRoute($item->slug, 0, $item->language);
    $item->path = FinderIndexerHelper::getContentPath($item->route);

    // Get the menu title if it exists.
    $title = $this->getItemMenuTitle($item->url);

    // Adjust the title if necessary.
    if (!empty($title) && $this->params->get('use_menu_title', true))
    {
        $item->title = $title;
    }

    /*
     * Add the meta-data processing instructions based on the contact
     * configuration parameters.
     */
    // Handle the contact position.
    $item->addInstruction(FinderIndexer::META_CONTEXT, 'secretary');

    // Add the type taxonomy data.
    $item->addTaxonomy('Type', 'Show');

    // Add the language taxonomy data.
    $item->addTaxonomy('Language', $item->language);

    // Get content extras.
    FinderIndexerHelper::getContentExtras($item);

    // Index the item.
    $test = $this->indexer->index($item);
}

/**
 * Method to setup the indexer to be run.
 *
 * @return  boolean  True on success.
 *
 * @since   2.5
 */
protected function setup()
{
    // Load dependent classes.
    require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_agshows/helpers/route.php';

    return true;
}

/**
 * Method to get the SQL query used to retrieve the list of content items.
 *
 * @param   mixed  $query  A JDatabaseQuery object or null.
 *
 * @return  JDatabaseQuery  A database object.
 *
 * @since   2.5
 */
protected function getListQuery($query = null)
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // Check if we can use the supplied SQL query.
    $query = $query instanceof JDatabaseQuery ? $query : $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.description, a.details AS info, a.secretary')
        ->select('a.state, a.catid')
        ->select('a.created_by_alias, a.modified, a.modified_by')
        ->select('a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.metadata, a.language')
        ->select('a.publish_up AS publish_start_date, a.publish_down AS publish_end_date')
        ->select('c.title AS category, c.published AS cat_state, c.access AS cat_access');

    // Handle the alias CASE WHEN portion of the query
    $case_when_item_alias = ' CASE WHEN ';
    $case_when_item_alias .= $query->charLength('a.alias', '!=', '0');
    $case_when_item_alias .= ' THEN ';
    $a_id = $query->castAsChar('a.id');
    $case_when_item_alias .= $query->concatenate(array($a_id, 'a.alias'), ':');
    $case_when_item_alias .= ' ELSE ';
    $case_when_item_alias .= $a_id . ' END as slug';
    $query->select($case_when_item_alias);

    $case_when_category_alias = ' CASE WHEN ';
    $case_when_category_alias .= $query->charLength('c.alias', '!=', '0');
    $case_when_category_alias .= ' THEN ';
    $c_id = $query->castAsChar('c.id');
    $case_when_category_alias .= $query->concatenate(array($c_id, 'c.alias'), ':');
    $case_when_category_alias .= ' ELSE ';
    $case_when_category_alias .= $c_id . ' END as catslug';
    $query->select($case_when_category_alias)

        ->select('us.name AS secretary')
        ->from('#__agshows_shows AS a')
        ->join('LEFT', '#__categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid')
        ->join('LEFT', '#__users AS us ON us.id = a.secretary');

    return $query;
}
```

I do have the rest of the standard functions for dealing with saved content and deleted content but they are almost identical to the core components.

I have noticed that the detail hover box doesn't appear on any of my indexed content like it does for articles and contacts. Is this a sign its not indexing properly.

I have debugged as best I can but just can't find whats going on.

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue, I accidentally omitted the access column from the database query. So it was saving with an access level of 0 and therefore not returning any results.

New `getListQuery` function:

```
protected function getListQuery($query = null) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // Check if we can use the supplied SQL query.
    $query = $query instanceof JDatabaseQuery ? $query : $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.description, a.details AS info, a.secretary')
        ->select('a.state, a.catid')
        ->select('a.created_by_alias, a.modified, a.modified_by')
        ->select('a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.metadata, a.language, a.access')
        ->select('a.publish_up AS publish_start_date, a.publish_down AS publish_end_date')
        ->select('c.title AS category, c.published AS cat_state, c.access AS cat_access');

    // Handle the alias CASE WHEN portion of the query
    $case_when_item_alias = ' CASE WHEN ';
    $case_when_item_alias .= $query->charLength('a.alias', '!=', '0');
    $case_when_item_alias .= ' THEN ';
    $a_id = $query->castAsChar('a.id');
    $case_when_item_alias .= $query->concatenate(array($a_id, 'a.alias'), ':');
    $case_when_item_alias .= ' ELSE ';
    $case_when_item_alias .= $a_id . ' END as slug';
    $query->select($case_when_item_alias);

    $case_when_category_alias = ' CASE WHEN ';
    $case_when_category_alias .= $query->charLength('c.alias', '!=', '0');
    $case_when_category_alias .= ' THEN ';
    $c_id = $query->castAsChar('c.id');
    $case_when_category_alias .= $query->concatenate(array($c_id, 'c.alias'), ':');
    $case_when_category_alias .= ' ELSE ';
    $case_when_category_alias .= $c_id . ' END as catslug';
    $query->select($case_when_category_alias)

        ->select('us.name AS secretary')
        ->from('#__agshows_shows AS a')
        ->join('LEFT', '#__categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid')
        ->join('LEFT', '#__users AS us ON us.id = a.secretary');

    return $query;
}
```

All fixed now!